# iOs: Low frame per second(fps) for VGA resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg, video-streaming, wowza

I'm facing an  issue in broadcasting video from one iPhone to another iPhone.

The issue is when I view the friend's live video in my iPhone, the frame per second(fps) is very low(it is 12fps). Video quality and audio is looking fine but the only problem is **fps**.

I don't know where I need to config/change the code to convert from variable fps to constant fps. Also to increase the fps as `**24/30**`.

The resolution I used for broadcasting

```
RESOLUTION_VGA,     // 480x640px (landscape) & 640x480px (portrait)
```

I'm using following libraries for streaming

1. MediaLibiOS - [link](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos)
2. Ffmpeg-2.2.1
3. CommLibiOS
4. libx264-r2409

Wowza is a Media Server and iOS target version is 7.0

Please help !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the network just isn't strong to offer so much bandwidth?

Comment: I have set bit rate as 7200000bits(~900 Kilobytes) and video codec as FLV1. The other commercial video streaming apps are working fine in my phone.

Comment: Try running Instruments on the transmitter as well as the receiver and see if it's a memory/CPU issue.